# Why do I have to indicate the index in my Rx stream?

Tags: rxjs

I am calling out to a db with `knex` and then using that result to make a `REST` call with `axios`.  I am using `Observable`s from `rx` to manage the whole thing.  Here is my code that is not working like I want:

```
return Observable
        .fromPromise(knex('users').where({id: userId}).select('user_name'))
        .map(res => getCreatePlaylistConfig(res[0].user_name))
        .concatMap(axios)
        .toPromise();

function getCreatePlaylistConfig(userName) {
    return {
        url: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/' + userName + '/playlists',
        method: 'POST'
    }
}
```

I am having to use the `index` in the `map` where I call the `getCreatePlaylistConfig` to make the code work.  I logged out the object that came back from the `knex` call with:

`do(res => console.log(res)`

and it looks like this:

```
[ { user_name: 'joe'} ]
```

It is an array like I would expect, but I thought the `map` would iterate through the array.  Why is it requiring the `index`?  How do I make this code work properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that your code is not flattening the result from the `Promise`. When you use `fromPromise` you are really saying that you want to create an `Observable` that emits a single value and then completes (if you look at the source for `fromPromise` this is exactly what it does). In your case that single value is an array.

The `map` operator will act on each value that is emitted from the source Observable and *map* it to another value. However, it will make no attempt to *flatten* that data because that would be rather presumptuous of it.

If you want to avoid explicitly using an indexing operator you need to use an operator that will flatten it instead.

```
return Observable
        .fromPromise(knex('users').where({id: userId}).select('user_name'))
         //flatMap implicitly converts an array into an Observable
         //so you need to use the identity function here
        .flatMap(res => res, 
                  //This will be called for each item in the array
                 (res, item) => getCreatePlaylistConfig(item.userName))
        .concatMap(axios)
        .toPromise();

function getCreatePlaylistConfig(userName) {
    return {
        url: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/' + userName + '/playlists',
        method: 'POST'
    }
}
```